# Select last few N items using chained CSS selectors for a deeply nested html element

Tags: html, css, web

I have a HTML markup of the following structure,

```
<div class='items'>
 <time></time>
 <ol class='category'>
   <li class='book'>
    <a href></a>
    <div class='tooltip'>
    <div>
   </li>
 <ol>
</div>
```

In the above markup, the div with the class *tooltip* is a tooltip whose position needs to be controlled so that I can either show it to the left or right by applying a class. I need to select the last 4 items, no matter how many items are rendered on the screen.

I came up with the markup as follows to achieve that,

```
// select last four bars and display tooltip on left
div.items{
  &:last-of-type {
    ol > li:nth-last-child(-n + 4) > .tooltip {
      left: calc(-1 * #{$tooltip-width});
   }
  }
}
```

This selects only the last div[class='items'] and not the last 4 divs[class='items']
Kindly let me know what CSS I'm missing here

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be easier to investigate.

Comment: _“This selects only the last div[class='items']”_ - _that_ is probably the effect of `&:last-of-type` …? _“and not the last 4 divs[class='items']”_ - you are applying `:nth-last-child` on the `li` elements, it is not selecting divs to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Inside the div with class 'items', I wanted to select ol element. I understand my CSS markup is wrong, Im not too familiar with CSS selectors, hence I asked for clarification

Comment: By “items”, you mean your div elements with the class `item`, or are you talking about the _list_ items? Also, as was already said in first comment, you should provide a _proper_ [mre] here first of all.

Comment: @CBroe By items I mean, selecting div tags with the class name 'items'

Comment: Well then start with applying `:nth-last-child` to those actually, instead of the list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild) about nth-last child, but this should basically do the trick of selecting the last 4 children with just CSS

```
.className a:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    /*declarations*/
}
```

In your case :

```
// select last four bars and display tooltip on left
.items {
   div.tooltip:nth-last-child(-n + 4) {
     left: calc(-1 * #{$tooltip-width});
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!